# I have a problem with value of my key in Redis

Tags: redis

I have redis HASH Data base with:
key: rq:job:test-uid-10--ufddfK9tQVPE3HdSv7N
field: meta
value of key: \x80\x05\x95\xb4\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00}\x94(\x8c\x04uuid\x94\x8c test-uid-10--ufddfK9tQVPE3HdSv7N\x94\x8c\x02db\x94\x8c\x04main\x94\x8c\x05utime\x94J7\xcb\xcde\x8c\x05etime\x94J7\xcb\xcde\x8c\x08template\x94\x8c\x09TEMPLATE9\x94\x8c\x09input_url\x94\x8cBhttps://storage-int-dev.1tv.ru/input/2023-01-10-22-48-09-S0376.mxf\x94\x8c\x08bitrates\x94\x8c\x03box\x94\x8c\x07BoxList\x94\x93\x94)\x81\x94(\x8c\x03350\x94\x8c\x03950\x94\x8c\x043800\x94e}\x94(\x8c\x09box_class\x94\x8c\x15dynaconf.utils.boxing\x94\x8c\x07DynaBox\x94\x93\x94\x8c\x0bbox_options\x94}\x94(\x8c\x0e__box_heritage\x94h\x17)\x81\x94(\x8c\x04name\x94\x8c\x1f\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd1\x8b mbr HD+CROP+Logo\x94h\x0bh\x0f\x8c\x08commands\x94h\x0e)\x81\x94h\x0e)\x81\x94(\x8c\x07cpu_cpu\x94\x8c-/bin/bash run_templates_one.sh with_crop_logo\x94e}\x94(h\x14h\x0c\x8c\x03Box\x94\x93\x94h\x18}\x94\x8c\x0bbox_org_ref\x94\x8a\x06\x80\x7f\x0e\x86\xa3\x7fuba}\x94(h\x14h\x17h\x18}\x94(h\x1ah\x1bh\x1e\x86\x94\x8c\x0bdefault_box\x94\x89\x8c\x10default_box_attr\x94h\x17\x8c\x0econversion_box\x94\x88\x8c\x0fbox_safe_prefix\x94\x8c\x01x\x94\x8c\x0afrozen_box\x94\x89\x8c\x10camel_killer_box\x94\x89\x8c\x11modify_tuples_box\x94\x89\x8c\x0ebox_duplicates\x94\x8c\x06ignore\x94\x8c\x0bordered_box\x94\x89\x8c\x10box_intact_types\x94)uh'\x8a\x06@}\x0e\x86\xa3\x7fubu}\x94\x8c\x0b_box_config\x94}\x94(\x8c\x0b__converted\x94\x8f\x94(h\x1eh\x1ch\x0b\x90h\x1aN\x8c\x09__created\x94\x88\x8c\x14__ordered_box_values\x94]\x94h+\x89h,h\x17h-\x88h.h/h0\x89h1\x89h2\x89h3h4h5\x89h6)usbh\x0b\x86\x94h+\x89h,h\x17h-\x88h.h/h0\x89h1\x89h2\x89h3h4h5\x89h6)uh'\x8a\x06@\x7f\x0e\x86\xa3\x7fub\x8c\x08hostname\x94\x8c\x11test-transcoder-1\x94\x8c\x08priority\x94\x8c\x03low\x94\x8c\x0einput_filename\x94\x8c02023-01-10-22-48-09-S0376_3173444.8334065545.mxf\x94\x8c\x06status\x94K\x01\x8c\x0d**export_status**\x94K\x00\x8c\x09mediainfo\x94X<\x1a\x00\x00{\x0a    "streams": [\x0a        {\x0a            "index": 0,\x0a            "codec_name": "mpeg2video",\x0a            "codec_long_name": "unknown",\x0a            "profile": "0",\x0a            "codec_type": "video",\x0a            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",\x0a            "codec_tag": "0x0000",\x0a            "width": 1920,\x0a            "height": 1080,\x0a            "coded_width": 0,\x0a            "coded_height": 0,\x0a            "closed_captions": 0,\x0a            "film_grain": 0,\x0a            "has_b_frames": 1,\x0a            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",\x0a            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",\x0a            "pix_fmt": "yuv422p",\x0a            "level": 2,\x0a            "color_range": "tv",\x0a            "color_space": "bt709",\x0a            "color_transfer": "bt709",\x0a            "color_primaries": "bt709",\x0a            "chroma_location": "topleft",\x0a            "field_order": "tt",\x0a            "refs": 1,\x0a            "r_frame_rate": "25/1",\x0a            "avg_frame_rate": "25/1",\x0a            "time_base": "1/25",\x0a            "start_pts": 0,\x0a            "start_time": "0.000000",\x0a            "duration_ts": 1195,\x0a            "duration": "47.800000",\x0a            "bit_rate": "50000000",\x0a            "extradata_size": 98,\x0a            "disposition": {\x0a                "default": 0,\x0a                "dub": 0,\x0a                "original": 0,\x0a                "comment": 0,\x0a                "lyrics": 0,\x0a                "karaoke": 0,\x0a                "forced": 0,\x0a                "hearing_impaired": 0,\x0a                "visual_impaired": 0,\x0a                "clean_effects": 0,\x0a                "attached_pic": 0,\x0a                "timed_thumbnails": 0,\x0a                "captions": 0,\x0a                "descriptions": 0,\x0a                "metadata": 0,\x0a                "dependent": 0,\x0a                "still_image": 0\x0a            },\x0a            "tags": {\x0a                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D1213E9EBB33A461404549905A3A6DB1860249538D9",\x0a                "file_package_name": "Source Package",\x0a                "track_name": "Track 2"\x0a            },\x0a            "side_data_list": [\x0a                {\x0a                    "side_data_type": "CPB properties",\x0a                    "max_bitrate": 50000000,\x0a                    "min_bitrate": 0,\x0a                    "avg_bitrate": 0,\x0a                    "buffer_size": 17825792,\x0a                    "vbv_delay": -1\x0a                }\x0a            ]\x0a        },\x0a        {\x0a            "index": 1,\x0a            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",\x0a            "codec_long_name": "unknown",\x0a            "codec_type": "audio",\x0a            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",\x0a            "codec_tag": "0x0000",\x0a            "sample_fmt": "s32",\x0a            "sample_rate": "48000",\x0a            "channels": 1,\x0a            "bits_per_sample": 24,\x0a            "initial_padding": 0,\x0a            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",\x0a            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",\x0a            "time_base": "1/48000",\x0a            "start_pts": 0,\x0a            "start_time": "0.000000",\x0a            "duration_ts": 2294400,\x0a            "duration": "47.800000",\x0a            "bit_rate": "1152000",\x0a            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",\x0a            "disposition": {\x0a                "default": 0,\x0a                "dub": 0,\x0a                "original": 0,\x0a                "comment": 0,\x0a                "lyrics": 0,\x0a                "karaoke": 0,\x0a                "forced": 0,\x0a                "hearing_impaired": 0,\x0a                "visual_impaired": 0,\x0a                "clean_effects": 0,\x0a                "attached_pic": 0,\x0a                "timed_thumbnails": 0,\x0a                "captions": 0,\x0a                "descriptions": 0,\x0a                "metadata": 0,\x0a                "dependent": 0,\x0a                "still_image": 0\x0a            },\x0a            "tags": {\x0a                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D1213E9EBB33A461404549905A3A6DB1860249538D9",\x0a                "file_package_name": "Source Package",\x0a                "track_name": "Track 3"\x0a            }\x0a        },\x0a        {\x0a            "index": 2,\x0a            "codec_name": "pcm_s24le",\x0a            "codec_long_name": "unknown",\x0a            "codec_type": "audio",\x0a            "codec_tag_string": "[0][0][0][0]",\x0a            "codec_tag": "0x0000",\x0a            "sample_fmt": "s32",\x0a            "sample_rate": "48000",\x0a            "channels": 1,\x0a            "bits_per_sample": 24,\x0a            "initial_padding": 0,\x0a            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",\x0a            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",\x0a            "time_base": "1/48000",\x0a            "start_pts": 0,\x0a            "start_time": "0.000000",\x0a            "duration_ts": 2294400,\x0a            "duration": "47.800000",\x0a            "bit_rate": "1152000",\x0a            "bits_per_raw_sample": "24",\x0a            "disposition": {\x0a                "default": 0,\x0a                "dub": 0,\x0a                "original": 0,\x0a                "comment": 0,\x0a                "lyrics": 0,\x0a                "karaoke": 0,\x0a                "forced": 0,\x0a                "hearing_impaired": 0,\x0a                "visual_impaired": 0,\x0a                "clean_effects": 0,\x0a                "attached_pic": 0,\x0a                "timed_thumbnails": 0,\x0a                "captions": 0,\x0a                "descriptions": 0,\x0a                "metadata": 0,\x0a                "dependent": 0,\x0a                "still_image": 0\x0a            },\x0a            "tags": {\x0a                "file_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D1213E9EBB33A461404549905A3A6DB1860249538D9",\x0a                "file_package_name": "Source Package",\x0a                "track_name": "Track 4"\x0a            }\x0a        }\x0a    ],\x0a    "format": {\x0a        "filename": "https://storage-int-dev.1tv.ru/input/2023-01-10-22-48-09-S0376.mxf",\x0a        "nb_streams": 3,\x0a        "nb_programs": 0,\x0a        "format_name": "mxf",\x0a        "start_time": "0.000000",\x0a        "duration": "47.800000",\x0a        "size": "314621536",\x0a        "bit_rate": "52656324",\x0a        "probe_score": 100,\x0a        "tags": {\x0a            "operational_pattern_ul": "060e2b34.04010101.0d010201.01010900",\x0a            "toolkit_version_num": "4.7.6.10135.1",\x0a            "uid": "114bef23-9119-11ed-9290-1860249538d9",\x0a            "generation_uid": "114bef24-9119-11ed-89f1-1860249538d9", Inc.",\x0a            "product_name": "Avid MediaProcessor Plug-In",\x0a            "product_version": "1.0.47.10029.1",\x0a            "application_platform": "MXF::SDK (4.7.6) on Win64",\x0a            "product_uid": "d49f75ba-4965-4cfa-9d11-cd87206287e0",\x0a            "modification_date": "2023-01-10T19:00:36.872000Z",\x0a            "material_package_umid": "0x060A2B340101010501010D12130A1CDB3B461404549905A3AE321860249538D9",\x0a            "timecode": "00:02:00:00"\x0a        }\x0a    }\x0a}\x0a\x94\x8c\x05width\x94M\x80\x07\x8c\x06height\x94M8\x04\x8c\x08duration\x94G@G\xe6fffff\x8c\x08filesize\x94J`\xbe\xc0\x12\x8c\x0bavg_bitrate\x94G@I\x1b\xc6\xa7\xef\x9d\xb2u

This is the bites and i need to change the export_status, how can i make it?! I made it in a bold in this text.

I tryed connected to my redis get the value of my key and changed it manualy. But i can't decode it.

```
import redis

def get_hash():
    conn = redis.Redis('localhost', 6379)
    job = conn.hget("rq:job:uid-test-1-", "meta")
    print(job.decode())

get_hash()
```

i've got this issue:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Comment: This looks like binary data and not UTF-8. What format is the data in?

Comment: Also, putting the data itself in a code block would make this question a *lot* easier to read.

Comment: I did'n find what kind of codec redis use...

Comment: Redis doesn't use a codec. It only stores bytes.

Comment: So, how can i read this value? 'utf-8' does't work

Comment: What is the data? Who wrote it there? What format did they use?